# Не отображается кнопка pause на хостинге firebase, но на локалхосте все в порядке, почему?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Плеер писал сам.
На локалхосте при нажатие на кнопку play/pause они соответственно изменяется так как нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я залил все это на хостинг firebase: прописал yarn build -> firebase deploy.
Вот что на хосте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но если нажать на "пустое" пространство, то play появляется

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, чем отличается картинка "pause" от картинки "play" путь другой, например. И чем отличаются ссылки на них на странице.

Comment: Эти кнопки - div блоки

Comment: и что? чем отличаются друг от друга?